# Oracle: Trigger not working

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I have this trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trig_update_process_info
  AFTER INSERT ON rocessstep FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  audit_time TIMESTAMP(6);
  found_flag NUMBER DEFAULT 0;
BEGIN

  SELECT MAX(lastupdatetime) INTO audit_time
    FROM processinfo
   WHERE instance = :new.instance;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN no_data_found THEN
    found_flag := NULL;

    IF found_flag IS NULL
    THEN
      INSERT INTO processinfo
       VALUES (:new.instance, :new.step, :new.status, :new.iteration, :new.audittime);
    ELSE
      IF :new.audittime > audit_time
      THEN
        UPDATE processinfo
        SET step = :new.step, lastupdatetime = :new.audittime, status = :new.status, iteration = :new.iteration
        WHERE instance = :new.instance;
      END IF;
    END IF;
END;
```

But it is not working. Can you tell me what is wrong with this trigger?

Here is the target table:

```
CREATE TABLE PROCESSINFO(
    INSTANCE   CHAR(36 BYTE) NOT NULL, 
    STEP       VARCHAR2(128 BYTE) NOT NULL, 
    STATUS     NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL,
    ITERATION  NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL,
    LASTUPDATETIME TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL
);
```

Thanks

Comment: What is not working? please provide everything people need to know so they can help you.

Comment: "*it is not working*" is neither a valid Oracle message nor is it an acceptable problem description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query can never throw `no_data_found` because of the aggregate. Instead, if there is no matching data then `audit_time` will be null, so you can test for that instead - no need for a `found_flag` at all. And as written, the entire if/else section is inside the exception handler, so it can never be evaluated (presumably you're expecting to hit the else part if no exception is thrown, but you don't have a separate begin/end around the query, so you haven't structured the block correctly).

```
...
BEGIN
  SELECT MAX(LASTUPDATETIME) INTO AUDIT_TIME FROM PROCESSINFO
  WHERE INSTANCE = :NEW.INSTANCE;

  IF AUDIT_TIME IS NULL 
  THEN
    INSERT INTO PROCESSINFO (INSTANCE, STEP, STATUS, ITERATION, LASTUPDATETIME)
      VALUES (:NEW.INSTANCE, :NEW.STEP, :NEW.STATUS, :NEW.ITERATION, :NEW.AUDITTIME);
  ELIF :NEW.AUDITTIME > AUDIT_TIME THEN 
    UPDATE PROCESSINFO SET STEP = :NEW.STEP, LASTUPDATETIME = :NEW.AUDITTIME,
      STATUS = :NEW.STATUS, ITERATION = :NEW.ITERATION
    WHERE INSTANCE = :NEW.INSTANCE;
  END IF;
END;
```

It looks like there is only expected to be one row in `processinfo` for each `instance` anyway, so you could also consider a merge statement instead of choosing whether to update or insert.

The `ON ROCESSSTEP` looks odd too but if that table name is wrong the trigger wouldn't be created at all, rather than just 'not working'.